# Save image android sqlite

Tags: android, database, image

I need help with on creating the database for android application. The app that i am doing allows users to capture an image and save it in the database. I am not sure on how to save the image into the database. What data type should i use? and how should the codes look like. I know in order to create an android database, i should first create a class that defines all getter and setter methods, and then create a database handler class. Where do i define the data type for image? I am very new to android developement.

Answer (score 1):

Just store images in sdcard and save the relevant path of those images in SQLite database.

In your need, put the images in either drawable folder or in asset folder then store its
name(with question ID or number also) in SQLite and use it in application.

for example. save one image with name question1 in drawable folder, now you get data for question 1 from your sqlite database, then from cursor's index if question is 1 then set, ex: ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image); image.setImageResource(R.drawable.question1)